# JQuery .html() method and external scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

i'm loading, using the JQuery **ajax()** method, an external page with both html and javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myfile.js"></script>
<p>This is some HTML</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
     alert("This is inline JS");
</script>
```

and setting the results into a div element, using the **html()** method.

While the html() method properly evaluates the inline JS code, it doesn't download and evaluate the external JS file "myfile.js".

Any tip for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you control the external page you could change this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myfile.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://host/path/myfile.js"></script>
```

---

Demo: http://jsbin.com/ucomu3/3 loads http://jsbin.com/otopi/3 via `$.ajax` and sets the returned data via `html()` http://jsbin.com/otopi/3 contains an inline script tag and one with a full qualified URL in the src-attribute which points to http://jsbin.com/uyova3

So if you open http://jsbin.com/ucomu3/3 you see "This is some HTML" and two alerts which say "I'm the external local js" and "This is inline JS"

Comment: Changing the src path actually doesn't solve the problem.
It seems that JQuery, when setting the results into the div with the html() method, doesn't download the external scripts from the specified location, and doesn't evaluates it's contents.

Comment: Yeah, because that's not JQuery's job. It's the job of the browser.

Comment: The jQuery.getScript() method, as stated in the documentation, "Load a JavaScript file from the server using a GET HTTP request, then execute it." 
If it's possible, i would avoid parsing the "script" tags from the results, and then call explicitly the getScript() method for each of them.

Comment: Changing the src should solve the problem because jQuery calls the `evalScript` function for every `script` tag it finds in the `data` parameter passed in to the success function of the `$.ajax` call. So @middus you are just wrong as it actually is jQuery's job to load the scripts

Comment: Check expanded answer for demo links

Answer (score 1):

Try to use an absolute address in the `src`-attribute of your `<script>`.